# Using Selected="Selected" from dynamic list of options

Tags: php, html

I'm posting variables from my form on to another form (a search records form), this will have all the variables that are being posted to the current form and place within `INPUT` field or `SELECT` fields. Any fields which are `INPUT` type I can `POST` to using the `Value=""` section of the `INPUT`. Now for `SELECT` I have a little problem, any small list that I prepopulate in the code are fine I have used this code below

```
<label>Fuel</label>
<select tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '1' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Mains gas</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '2' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Wood or coal fire</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '3' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Oil</option>
<option value="4" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '4' ? 'selected' : '')?>>Electric storage heaters</option>
<option value="5" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '5' ? 'selected' : '')?>>LPG or bottled gas</option>
<option value="6" <?php echo ($searchfuel == '6' ? 'selected' : '')?>>No central heating system</option>
</select>
```

As I said when I run the Sear records form and return the posted variables, this works great. My problem is with big data sets within `SELECT` which are from the database, this is what I have currently, which is perfect to get data into a `SELECT` but how can I post a variable to it in a similar way to the previous code?

```
<label>Fuel Type</label> 
<?php $fueltype = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_fueltype'); 
if(!$fueltype->count()) { echo 'Problem'; } else { ?> 
<select tabindex="1" id="propertyfueltype" name="propertyfueltype"> 
<?php foreach ($fueltype->results() as $fueltype) { ?> 
<option value="<?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?>"><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option> 
<?php } } ?> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
<option
    value="<?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?>"
    <?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType == $searchfuel ? "selected" : ""; ?>
><?php echo $fueltype->PropertyFuelType; ?></option>
```

Having said that, I would recommend using a PHP templating system; or at least convert this logic into a function.

Comment: Thanks, how you mean a PHP templating system, I'm not sure on how to turn if into a function, will google.

Comment: Just write a generic function to display select boxes so that you can use it more than one place.

Comment: Ah ok and then all I would need to change would be the SQL and the variables?